# Different macro based on where file is included

Tags: c

I have a `master.c` and `slave.c` file. Both are compiled seperately, producing different [contiki-ng](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng) modules.

As they both use a similar function, I created a `helpers.h`  and `helpers.c` file, and added `#include "helpers.h"` to `main.c` and `slave.c` to deduplicate this function.

Additionally, I need to use the `LOG_INFO` function from [log.h](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/blob/develop/os/sys/log.h) for logging in both `slave.c`/`master.c` and in `helpers.c`. [log.h](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/blob/develop/os/sys/log.h) requires the macro `LOG_MODULE` to be set to the name of the Module (`Master` or `Slave`).

*master.c*:

```
#define LOG_MODULE "Master"
#include "sys/log.h"

#include "helpers.h"

void main() {
    do_something();
}
```

*slave.c*:

```
#define LOG_MODULE "Slave"
#include "sys/log.h"

#include "helpers.h"

void main() {
    do_something();
}
```

*helpers.h*:

```
void do_something();
```

*helpers.c*:

```
#include "sys/log.h"
#include "helpers.h"
void do_something() {
    ...
    LOG_INFO("Result: x"); 
    ...
}
```

My problem is the following:

Even though I include "helpers.h"  AFTER defining `LOG_MODULE` in `master.c`/`slave.c`, I still get a complaint about `LOG_MODULE` not being defined when I use `LOG_INFO` in `helpers.c`.

What is a proper and elegant solution to define `LOG_MODULE` with their respective values in `slave.c` and `master.c`, and have that definition used by `helpers.c`?

Comment: `I include "helpers.h" AFTER defining LOG_MODULE` - no, `LOG_MODULE` is not defined there. You clearly included `sys/log.h` and then `helpers.h`. There is no `#define LOG_MODULE` in `helpers.c`. This is the link to log.h : https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/blob/develop/os/sys/log.h

Comment: You only define `LOG_MODULE` in files `master.c` and `slave.c`, but not in `helpers.c` You need an extra `#define LOG_MODULE "Helpers"` in that file

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes - what is a proper solution that makes `helpers.c` use the respective `LOG_MODULE` value from `master.c` / `slave.c`? If I define `LOG_MODULE` in `helpers.c`, it will not have the correct value.

Comment: Unless you add an extra parameter to the functions from `helpers.c` where you pass that string, different compilation units do not share any macros from each other.#

Comment: Your master and slave are separate programs that share the code in helpers. Separate the builds, so that you make two helper objects: one for the master and one for the slave. Then define the cc argument `-DLOG_MODULE="whatever"` in the build procedures, e.g. in the Makefile. That should work even if the string literal is used with string-literal concatenation.

Comment: @MOehm How would I do that with the contiki-ng [Makefile](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/blob/develop/examples/nullnet/Makefile)? I tried to add a line `master: CFLAGS += -DLOG_MODULE="whatever"`, but that did not work. (->LOG_MODULE not error defined in `helpers.c`. if I left the LOG_MODULE in `master.c`, I got a `redefined` error, so in general this seems to work)

Comment: You should compile two helper objects and then make sure that each is compiled with the right `LOG_MODULE` set. That's probably something best declared in a rule, not with a variable. (Perhaps you also need to escape the quotes, so that they appear in the definition of the preprocessor symbol.)

Comment: @MOehm Phew.. Unfortunately, I'm not so firm with writing Makefiles. Can you give me some guidance on how to achieve this with the Makefile linked above?

Comment: Hm. I'm not so good with contiki-ng. Perhaps what I suggest isn't such a good solution after all.

Comment: @MOehm I actually believe that your proposed solution is better than the inlining solution proposed in the answer below. Would love some advice on how to achieve it :)

Comment: Okay. Most of the "meat" of the makefile is actually in `Makefile.include`, which is huge. Apparently, you can define a `TARGET`. When the target is set, the main makefile tries to include `Makefile.$(TARGET)`, so you could perhaps create two targets for master and slave in `Makefile.master` and ´Makefile.slave` where you put the appropriate `-DLOG_TARGET=...` and then build `make TARGET=master` and ´make TARGET=slave`.

Comment: @MOehm Unfortunately that doesn't work, as TARGET needs to be set to the platform (i.e."SKY"): https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/The-Contiki%E2%80%90NG-build-system Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. I have no patience to work through the configuration of contiki-ng. I think the logging macro is too specialized and requiring a file-wise macro definition is not flexible enough. Perhaps you should address this question at a contiki dev?

Comment: (Having said that, here's one thing you could try: Declare a prototype `const char *module(void);` in `helper.h`. Then implement it as `const char *module(void) { return "master/slave"; }` in `master.c` and `slave.c`. Then define the macro `#define MODULE module()`. This could work, because in some configurations, the log macro uses a printf-like syntax, where a function could be used. In particular, the macro does not depend on juxtaposition of string literals.)

Answer (score 1):

The `helpers.c` is a separate compile unit and during the compilation of it, it only "sees" the #define's in the headers included only in that file.

To achieve what you what you want, you would need to:

1. Move the definition of all the functions that use logging from .c to .h file.
2. Make the logging functions inline in this header to prevent linking problems if `master.c` and `slave.c` are then linked together to create a single binary.

*helpers.h*

```
#include "sys/log.h"
inline void do_something() {
    ...
    LOG_INFO("Result: x"); 
    ...
}
```

Comment: I moved the `do_something` function to `helpers.h` and made it `inline`. However, I cannot remove `helpers.c`, as it includes other helper functions. Unfortunately, compiling this fails, because `helpers.h` is included in `helpers.c` (and LOG_MODULE is hence not defined). What would you suggest I do?

Comment: Regarding your point 3: `master.c` and `slave.c` are never linked together.

Comment: To make this work all the functions from helpers would need to to moved to the .h file or at least the ones that use the logging functionality that requires the LOG_MODULE macro.

Comment: I know that it doesn't look pretty to put the code into the header file. Also inlining the function might be problematic. Some functions just cannot be inlined e.g. if the function is recursive. Also you need to make sure all the functions it uses are declared before its body.
The easiest and the most robust solution would be to just leave the code as it was before and just assign the helpers it's own LOG_MODULE define e.g. ```#define LOG_MODULE "Helpers"```.

Comment: I did move all functions that required the LOG_MODULE macro to `helpers.h`. The remaining functions in `helpers.c` do not use the LOG_MODULE macro. However, as I `#include "helpers.h"` in `helpers.c`, the function get's inlined in the helpers.c compilation unit, which does not have LOG_MODULE defined.

Comment: Oh, but there is no need to include the ```helpers.h``` into the ```helpers.c``` unless you defined some types in ```helpers.h``` and then use them in ```helpers.c```. In general it is a good practice to keep as little includes in header files as possible.

Comment: As a last resort you could surround your logging inlined functions with ```#ifdef LOG_MODULE``` in the header.

Comment: I removed the `#include helpers.h` from `helpers.c`. However, I still get a `helpers.h:14:7: error: 'LOG_MODULE' undeclared (first use in this function)`  error. Somehow the `inline` does not seem to be working..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211699/discussion-between-dluzak-and-zulakis).

Comment: @Dluzak It is common sense to include a header file in its implementation file. This makes sure that all your public API is implemented the same way. Think about what happens if "helpers.h" declares `void f(long);` but "helpers.c" implements `void f(float p) { ...}`. The linker *can not* resolve this!